# Total only from products, excluding shipping on woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to delete shipping cost info from cart on Woocomerce. 
I want sth like that :
Product1 : 900$
Product2: 900$
Total: 1800$

without delivery info. I tried to hide this and its fine, but it also hide only products total, which i want to be visible.

Comment: Have you tried coding it? Is there any code to show so people can help?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following snippet on your `functions.php`

```
function disable_shipping_calc_on_cart( $show_shipping ) {
    if( is_cart() ) {
        return false;
    }
    return $show_shipping;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_ready_to_calc_shipping', 'disable_shipping_calc_on_cart', 99 );
```